# The getter 'iterator' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: iterator

Tags: flutter, dart, null

When I am making checkbox data and showing the selected checkbox to the next screen I am facing the above error. I am just doing copy-paste, I have no understanding of code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 void main() => runApp(Test());
 class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Select Services',
    home: RandomWords(),
  );
  return Container();
 }
}
```

this is a stateless widget

```
class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords>{
 final _suggestions = <String>['this is me1','this is me2','this is me3' ];
 final _saved = <String>['this is me1','this is me2','this is me3' ];
 final _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
```

here i am defining List View.

```
  void _pushSaved(){
   Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute<void>(
   // NEW lines from here...
   builder: (BuildContext context) {
    final tiles = _saved.map(
        (String pair) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          pair,
          style: _biggerFont,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
  final divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
    context: context,
    tiles: tiles,
  ).toList();
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: divided),
      );
    }, // ...to here.
  ),
);
}
Widget _buildSuggestions() {
  return ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
      if (i.isOdd) return Divider(); /*2*/
```

I am facing error in this section and the error is **"error: The method 'generateWordPairs' isn't defined for the type '_RandomWordsState'. (undefined_method at [ABC] lib\pages\test.dart:327)"** in console.

```
   final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
    if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
    _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
    }
   return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
});
}
```

This is the Rest code.

```
Widget _buildRow(String pair) {
  final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
  return ListTile(
   title: Text(
   pair,
   style: _biggerFont,
   ),
  trailing: Icon(
   alreadySaved ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outlined,
   color: alreadySaved ? Colors.cyan :null,
   ),
   onTap: (){
    setState(() {
     if (alreadySaved){
      _saved.remove(pair);
      }
    else{
    _saved.add(pair);
    }
   });
  },
  );
  }
```

This is a new screen code

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Startup Name Generator'),
    actions: [
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right), onPressed: _pushSaved),
    ],
  ),

  body: _buildSuggestions(),

 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

Remove these lines:

```
if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
  _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
}
```

and add this on top of your _buildSuggestions() function, if you want to change it afterwards

```
Widget _buildSuggestions() {
  _suggestions =  <String>['this is me1','this is me2','this is me3'];
  return ListView.builder( ...
```

if not, just remove the lines and don't add anything else.

### OLD

You need to import the package **english_words** in order to use the **generateWordPairs()** function.

(As for 26.04.2021) This is the newest version

```
english_words: ^4.0.0
```

Import it like this:

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
```

Comment: but I don't want to import the **english_words**. I just want to use a custom string. @lrsvmb

Comment: @parveen but you need the package in order to use this function: generateWordPairs().take(10)

Comment: so what I do if I want to use a custom string and I do not want to use this function "generateWordPairs().take(10)"

Comment: @parveen what do you mean by a custom string? Something you typed? Then use ["hello", "test", "custom_string"] instead of the function. It should look like this then: _suggestions.addAll(["hello", ....]);

Comment: when am applying this " _suggestions.addAll(["hello", ....]);" "Hello" is printing in infinite time. I just want to print only **String** values **"final _suggestions = <String>['this is me1','this is me2','this is me3' ];"**

Comment: @parveen I have updated my question according to your request.